# Error while executing IdeaJ (Java IDE) with PlayOnLinux under Linux

Tags: java, linux, intellij-idea, environment-variables

I installed IdeaJ to  basically start learning Java. I use a 32-bit Linux 18.3 KDE (here I'm using Xfce desktop), and so I downloaded the latest 32bit compatible version of Ideaj for Windows. I executed the installer with PlayOnLinux and all was ok. The installation on the virtual drive was fine.

Then, I tried to execute the shortcut of the idea.exe in the PlayOnLinux principal menu, but I got the error indicated in the image joined.
It asks me to set the JAVA_HOME environemnt variable, but I don't find the file where I have to modify/add the JAVA_HOME env variable, either in the virtual drive of PlayOnLinux or in my linux's files.

Can you help me find this file ? I wanna know after what link I have to put in the JAVA_HOME env variable, and where I can find it (I already have installed the JDK).
Thank you for your help.

[The error window after executing Idea_exe (the .exe file)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kCuf5.png)

Hardware and os properties :

System:    Host: *****

Kernel: 4.15.0-123-generic i686 (32 bit)

Desktop: Xfce 4.12.3 Distro: Linux Mint 18.3 Sylvia

Machine:   Mobo:

Acer model: E415SM v: 1.0

Bios: American Megatrends v: R01-A4

date: 01/16/2007

CPU:       Dual core Intel Pentium D (-MCP-) speed: 2992 MHz (max)

Graphics:  Card: Advanced Micro Devices [AMD/ATI] RC410 [Radeon Xpress 200/1100]

Display Server: X.Org 1.18.4 drivers: ati,radeon (unloaded: fbdev,vesa) Resolution: 1440x900@59.89hz
GLX Renderer: ATI RC410 GLX Version: 2.1 Mesa 18.0.5

Network:   Card: Marvell 88E8056 PCI-E Gigabit Ethernet Controller driver: sky2

Drives:    HDD Total Size: 250.1GB (25.8% used)

Info:      Processes: 197 Uptime: 3:55 Memory: 841.8/1755.4MB Client: Shell (bash) inxi: 2.2.35

Comment: Why on earth would you want to run the windows version of intellij on linux?

Comment: I have bad memories of trying to use the 32bit Linux version of PyCharm. It never worked. So I prefer using the Windows version.